# Как вставить данные заменяя часть значения числами из заданного диапазона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Как добавить в таблицу данные - `192.168.Х.9`, где `Х` - числа от 1 до 100?

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    cursor.executemany(f"""INSERT INTO ip VALUES ("192.168.{i()}.9") ;""")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
records = [[f"192.168.{i}.9"] for i in range(1, 101)]
cursor.executemany("insert into ip values(?)", records)
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Comment: @OverNiko, был рад помочь)